# What is the proper way to remove an element from a Hazelcast Map?

Tags: java, loops, dictionary, hazelcast

I need to remove an item from Hazelcast distributed Map and I use something like this code (simplified):

```
  public void realeaseBatchesById(int Id) {

    Iterator<Map.Entry<Long, WorkingBatch>> it = workingMap.entrySet().iterator();

    while (it.hasNext()) {
        WorkingBatch value = it.next().getValue();
        if (value.getServer().getId() == idd) {
        it.remove();
        }
    }

    }
```

but this code doesn't remove value, the size of the map is the same at the beginning as the size at the end.

When I see to [Hazelcast Javadoc](http://hazelcast.org/docs/latest/javadoc/com/hazelcast/core/IMap.html) I see that this interface defines only removing by key and by key with value. Does it mean I cannot use standard way how to remove value from the map?

Comment: Did you tried `equals` instead of `==` ?

Comment: There is no problem with finding values determined for removing - I found them. But doesn't work removing them via `it.remove()`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Removing an item from a map you can't do through an iterator. The iterator is a temporary copy of the entryset and changes on it don't reflect on the content of the map.

You approach isn't very scalable since you iterate over all entries in the map, imagine you have gigabytes of map entries.. roughly 50% needs to be send over the line before your item is found.

If you want to remove an item, you can do a:

```
map.remove(somekey)
```

But the big question is: how do you find your item. In you case your item apparently has some kind of server.id, so you might create an index on that id so you can do a fast lookup, and combine it with:

```
IMap.executeOnEntries(EntryProcessor entryProcessor, Predicate predicate);
```

When you create a predicate (that finds your entry) and create an entry processor (that can delete your entry), you can do a much more efficient delete.

Comment: Thanks, removing via map.remove(key) works for me. Is this operation thread safe or do I have to take care of it myself? I can iterate it because on the map there will about 20-30 values.

Comment: All operations on the map are threadsafe. But.. if you want to do multiple actions on a map in an atomic way, you need to apply e.g. (pessimsitic) locking, optimistic locking etc.

Comment: @pveentjer, I saw your last comment on https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/issues/486 showing a sample EntryProcessor for this use case. Can you confirm if such an EntryProcessor would delete the whole ENTRY from the IMap or just the VALUE associated with the KEY.

Comment: It removes the entry.  

   public static void main(String[] args){
        HazelcastInstance hz = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance();
       IMap map = hz.getMap("foo");
       map.put(1,1);
       map.executeOnKey(1, new DeleteEP());
        System.out.println(map.size());
    }

    public static class DeleteEP implements EntryProcessor{
        @Override
        public Object process(Map.Entry entry) {
            entry.setValue(null);
            return null;
        }
    }

Comment: @pveentjer I tried to delete million entries from Imap using Predicate based condition:IMap.executeOnEntries(new DeleteMillionsEntryProcessor(), predicate).This deleted entries from IMap as verified on mancenter map count. But, the exact number of deleted entries was shown up under "Hits". Is it because deletion via EntryProcessor refers to accessing the record and nullifying it. Also, is there a way to run GC manually as the millions of unreferenced objects result in my heap threshold reaching 70% and my application breaking down.